# How to change the color of legend markers?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to change the color of the legend item to black. I have done something similar in the past with `scatter` instead of `plot` but since I also want `fillstyle`, I need to use `plot`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import container

def ColorExtractor(cmap, colist):
    cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap(cmap)
    rbga = cmap(colist)
    return rbga

colors = ColorExtractor('Blues', [3/3, 3/3, 2/3, 1/3])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x_data = np.array([0.975, 0.75, 0.525])

y_min  = np.array([3, 3, 2])
y_max  = np.array([4, 4, 3])

for xs, ys, cols, labs, flstl in zip([x_data, x_data], [y_min, y_max], [colors, colors], ['$x_{min}$', '$x_{max}$'], ['bottom', 'top']):
    ax.plot(xs, ys, 'k:')
    for x, y, col in zip(xs, ys, cols):
        ax.plot(x, y, color=col, marker='<', label=labs, fillstyle=flstl, markeredgecolor='k', linestyle='none', markersize=10)

ax.set_xlim(0.5, 1)
ax.set_ylim(1, 5)

ax.set_xlabel('$x$', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('$y$', fontsize=15)

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles = [i[0] if isinstance(i, container.ErrorbarContainer) else i for i in handles]

by_label = dict(zip(labels, handles))

ax.legend(by_label.values(), by_label.keys(), loc=9, ncol=2, frameon=False)

leg = ax.get_legend()

for i in leg.legendHandles:
    i.set_color('k')
    i.set_markeredgecolor('k')
    #i.set_edgecolor('k')

plt.show()
```

Everything works fine except the last part which appears to not do anything. So, the color of the legend symbols remains blue instead of black. I also want the `edgecolor` to be black but I have commented it because `AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no attribute 'set_edgecolor'` spawns.

EDIT: As @Galunid pointed out, I should probably use `set_markeredgecolor` instead `set_edgecolor`. However, the main problem is that I want to change the color inside the legend markers to black.

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps `set_markeredgecolor` instead of `set_edgecolor`? See https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D

Comment: Thank you, @Galunid. I changed it as you said and no error spawned. However, the main issue is that I want to change the color inside the markers from blue to black.

Comment: Then `set_markerfacecolor` should do the trick

Comment: You'll need`set_markerfacecoloralt()` for the second color. [Docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_markerfacecoloralt).  See [this doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_fillstyle_reference.html) for an explanation of markers with two colors.

Comment: Thank you again, @Galunid. I am afraid nothing happens when I use `set_markerfacecolor` -- it is still blue and not black.

Comment: Thank you, @JohanC. I tried as you specified but if I put it in `ax.plot()` it changes the white to black, and if I put it in the loop at the end nothing happens. The markers in the legend are still blue and white instead of black and white.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the legend handles too soon, also the colors inside the plot will be changed. So, you'll need to make a copy of the handles and then color those copies.  Note that `set_markerfacecolor()` change the first color of the marker (`blue` in the example code). And `set_markerfacecoloralt()` would change the second color (the `white`). So, probably you'll want `set_markerfacecolor('black')` and leave the other color untouched.

Here is an example:

```py
from copy import copy

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles = [copy(i[0]) if isinstance(i, container.ErrorbarContainer) else copy(i) for i in handles]
for i in handles:
    i.set_markeredgecolor('black')
    i.set_markerfacecolor('crimson') # use 'black' to have that part black
    i.set_markerfacecoloralt('gold') # leave this line out in case the second color is already OK
by_label = dict(zip(labels, handles))
ax.legend(by_label.values(), by_label.keys(),  loc=9, ncol=2, frameon=False)
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thank you again, @JohanC! I followed your instruction and it worked perfectly. :)